# Bootstrap dropdown tabmenu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap tabmenu but now I want to make it a dropdown menu. I know that bootstrap have native support for this but I want the dropdown to be toggled only if the caret is clicked, if the rest of the menu item area are clicked that should work as an ordinary link. Do anyone know how to do this?

Here is what the code looks like today

[jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/q9Lg4axu/2/)

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code if you have self try ?

Comment: post your code (not all, only menu), create [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @jakobsjoqvist, may you to explain more clearly, what do you try to get? I saw in your code and didn't see any issues

Comment: I want the dropdown to be toggeled by clicking on the caret, and the rest of the button will work as an ordinary link.

Comment: smth like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/q9Lg4axu/3/)

Comment: Yes, thats the functionality I want, but I also want the to be more like one button than two... Anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/q9Lg4axu/4/

Comment: Thanks Igor! I only have one more question, is it possible to put two tabs on the right, so the result will be like https://gyazo.com/432377e8d9e6f0b545b9d42cf54c0e5c ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/q9Lg4axu/5/  but `pull-right` changes elements position.  and as a second option https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/zsj0dc6s/